# How do I remove all but some records based on a threshold?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(id int, name varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Adam')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Robert')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Copper')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Jumbo')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Jill')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Rocky')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Jack')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Lisa')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 'Amy')

SELECT *
FROM #TEMP


DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

I am trying to remove all but some records for those that have more than 3 names with the same id. Therefore, I am trying to get something like this:

```
id  name
1   Adam
1   Copper
1   John
2   Jill
2   Jack
2   Lisa
3   Amy
```

I am not understanding how to write this query. I have gotten to the extent of preserving one record but not a threshold of records:

```
;WITH FILTER AS
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM #TEMP
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) >=3 
)
SELECT id, MAX(name)
FROM #TEMP
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM FILTER)
GROUP BY id
UNION
SELECT id, name
FROM #TEMP
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM FILTER)
```

Gives me:

```
1   Robert
2   Rocky
3   Amy
```

Any suggestions? Oh by the way, I don't care what records are preserved while merging.

Comment: +1 for test scripts provided. It's easy to understand and answer such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(id int, name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Adam')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Robert')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Copper')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(1, 'Jumbo')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Jill')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Rocky')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Jack')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(2, 'Lisa')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(3, 'Amy')

SELECT *
FROM #TEMP;

WITH CTE(N) AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id)
 FROM #Temp
)
DELETE CTE WHERE N>3;

SELECT *
FROM #TEMP;

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: +1 Beautiful! Works perfect. Accepted as answer but could you please add some explanation?

Comment: this is very confusing that Legend wants to remove that extra row from output rows or delete from table :-).. good logic

Comment: @Legend I added link on MSDN.

Comment: +1 for testing with the OP data. This one works as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I will change your select like this (not tested)

```
select name from #temp group by name having count(id) > 3
```

then you can implement your query in a delete statement using your select as a where clause

Answer (score 0):

in inner query you can use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) function over (partition by id)
and then in outer query you have to give condition like below

```
select id,name from (
SELECT id,name, row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) count_id FROM #test
group by id, name ) 
where count_id <=3
```

Comment: Did you actually try this with the OP test data? It doesnt work!

Comment: On SQL Server 2008 this gives `incorrect syntax near where` because you need to alias the table. When you fix that issue by aliasing the table you get `Windowed functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.` When you change `order by 1` to `order by id` it *then* works. Pretty poor answer IMO.

Comment: please check this site ... http://mattberseth.com/blog/sql_server/.. This is my mistake to not check with database tag what you have added as sql server 2008, i have execute this query on oracle database. But this query should work on sql server as well...

Comment: @Jamiec - on one of my friend's system I have executed this query successfully.. please check whether you had done any minor mistake before ..

Comment: i copy/pasted your code directly underneath the OP's test setup (and had to change `#test` to `#temp`) but it fails with error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.`

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, you need to get rows when `id` occurrence 3 or more times

```
select t1.name,t1.id from tbl1 t1 
inner join tbl1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name, t1.id
having count(t1.id) > 2
```

Comment: Did you actually try this with the OP test data? It doesnt work!

Comment: When I tested your answer it gave all the ones, all the two's, and not the three.

Comment: Yes, it gives you as you mentioned, whats the problem?, he needs data when `id` occurrence 3 or more times!

Comment: The problem is the result is *nothing* like what the OP asked for.

Comment: OP `I am trying to remove all but some records for those that have more than 3 names with the same id`