# SQL Server : help removing duplicates in alternating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null, duplicates

```
Column 0    Column 1        Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
csus        00287y109       38          NULL        169
mbus        01185pag4       NULL        NULL        1
mbus        01185pag4       100         NULL        18
mbus        018033DR8       100         NULL        5
psus        20002309        26          NULL        5
cbus        025816aq2       NULL        NULL        169
cdus        02586tbj2X      101         NULL        1
cdus        02586tbj2X      NULL        NULL        1
```

I need to remove duplicate rows from this table named combined. However not all rows are duplicated nor are the duplicate rows identical in every column. An example duplicate is row 2 and row 3. The criteria for removal is if a row exists where Column 0 and Column 1 (these are the actual column headers) are identical, keep the row which has a value in Column 2, drop the row with NULL in Column 2 if a duplicate row exists with a value in Column 0 and Column 1 and Column 2. Null values are okay as you see in Column 2, row 6 because this is not duplicated with any other row based on my criteria which focuses on the first three columns. Null is not okay if Column 0 and Column 1 are duplicated. Column 3 is always NULL and it does not matter if Column 4 is duplicated or not. The final two rows, rows 7 and 8 are also duplicated. I would want to keep row 7 because it has a value in Column 2.

**Added** the expected result

```
Column 0    Column 1        Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
csus        00287y109       38          NULL        169
mbus        01185pag4       100         NULL        18
mbus        018033DR8       100         NULL        5
psus        20002309        26          NULL        5
cbus        025816aq2       NULL        NULL        169
cdus        02586tbj2X      101         NULL        1
```

In the desired result Row 2 and row 8 have been removed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565664/how-do-i-remove-all-but-some-records-based-on-a-threshold/7565818#7565818

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte as 
(
 Select * ,
 row_number() over (partition by [Column 0],[Column 1] order by [Column 2] desc) rn
 from Sample
)
Select * from cte
where rn=1
```

Demo [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b27a4/9)

On a side note `don't use spaces` in `column names`.If you really want to use space
 then use `underscore`

```
Updated

;with cte as 
 ( 
  Select * ,
  row_number() over (partition by [Column 0],[Column 1] order by [Column 2] desc) rn
  from Sample
 )
 Insert into final
 Select [Column 0], [Column 1], [Column 2], [Column 3] , [Column 4] 
 from cte 
 where rn=1
```

Comment: I agree about the spaces in the headers, but I can't change the headers.

Comment: I think this may have worked. I need to research it a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution does work. I have marked it as answered. I'm amazed you were able to answer it with such a succinct query.

Comment: Your solution does work to gather the results. If you don't mind could you assist me in converting this query into an insert into query? I already have a table built with the appropriate columns called final. I apologize for not mentioning this in my initial question.

Comment: Thank you this is an awesome result. I've bookmarked your blog too.